# Inconsistent results when using forEach and .shift()

Tags: javascript, loops

So here are two fiddles:

[Fiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/eoa3rtv9/3/)

[Fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/9oj7ycgm/)

When using forEach and then array shift inside the loop the output results in duplicates but if I use a regular for loop and use the shifted return as output it works correctly.

So the only difference between the two are:

```
var queueSize = testArray.length;

if (queueSize > 0) {
  testArray.forEach(function (loopData) {
    jQuery('.js-target').append(loopData+'<br>');
    testArray.shift();
  });
}
```

Compared to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
  var d = testArray.shift();

  jQuery('.js-target').append(d+'<br>');
}
```

To me the first one should work just as well as the second one. (The data is added to testArray with push i.e. to the end of the array). Is it something I'm not understanding with the shift function?

Comment: Maybe `forEach` works like `for...in`, and it reads all properties of the array, not only your keys.

Answer (score 2):

The shift method will remove the element at the start of the array.  So your array in the second example is being shortened at each iteration.

> The shift method removes the element at the zeroeth index and shifts
>   the values at consecutive indexes down, then returns the removed
>   value. If the length property is 0, undefined is returned.

See [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) for a full overview.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read this [explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#If_the_array_is_modified_during_iteration_other_elements_might_be_skipped.) in MDN it's really nice

The following example logs "one", "two", "four". When the entry containing the value "two" is reached, the first entry of the whole array is shifted off, which results in all remaining entries moving up one position. **Because element "four" is now at an earlier position in the array, "three" will be skipped. forEach() does not make a copy of the array before iterating.**

```
var words = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
words.forEach(function(word) {
  console.log(word);
  if (word === 'two') {
    words.shift();
  }
});
// one
// two
// four
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the elements of the array (as opposed to their values) during a forEach loop, it is going to behave differently to a regular for loop.

[From MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> The range of elements processed by forEach() is set before the first
>   invocation of callback. Elements that are appended to the array after
>   the call to forEach() begins will not be visited by callback. If the
>   values of existing elements of the array are changed, the value passed
>   to callback will be the value at the time forEach() visits them;
>   elements that are deleted before being visited are not visited.

Comment: To me this sentence: "The range of elements processed by forEach() is set before the first invocation of callback." sais that it should work since the shift happens inside the loop i.e. after the first invocation. If you look at the end of the result it looks like this (how come it loops through it twice but with 19 inbetween?):
20
19
20

If what you're saying is the cause the result should look more like this:
19
20
20

Comment: While the elements processed by forEach are determined at the start, their values change when you call shift.

Comment: Ah okay, but why do they "change" when you call shift, in what way? Edit: I guess this part: and shifts the values at consecutive indexes down